# Prove the next cyclic inequality

Tags: inequality, polynomials, fractions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Let $a,b,c>0$ such that $$a+b+c=1$$

prove that

$$cyclic\sum \frac {ab}{\sqrt {c+ab}}\le\frac {1}{2} $$

By symetrie, i proved it by assuming $a=b=c$ but i cannot justify this hypothesis.

Comment: from where does it come?

Comment: Not all cyclic sums attain their maximum/minimum at $a=b=c$. I fear this is too few to be called an actual attempt.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio The condition on $a,b,c $ is also cyclic.

Comment: It is enough to prove the homogeneous inequality
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{2ab}{\sqrt{c^2+(ab+ac+bc)}}\leq \sqrt{a+b+c} $$
under the constraint $a,b,c>0$. Attempts through the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality seem reasonable, but in any case the above inequality can be proved by brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{\sqrt{c+ab}}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{\sqrt{c(a+b+c)+ab}}\right)^2=\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{\sqrt{(a+c)(b+c)}}\right)^2\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(a+c)(b+c)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}ab\sum_{cyc}\frac{ab}{(a+c)(b+c)}\leq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{4},$$ which is easy after full expanding.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4b+a^4c-a^3b^2-a^3c^2-2a^3bc+2a^2b^2c)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2ab(a+b-c)\geq0.$$
Let $a\geq b\geq c$.

Thus,
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2ab(a+b-c)\geq$$
$$\geq(a-c)^2ac(a+c-b)+(b-c)^2bc(b+c-a)\geq$$
$$\geq(b-c)^2ac(a-b)+(b-c)^2bc(b-a)=(b-c)^2(a-b)^2c\geq0.$$
Done!

Comment: It seems strange, but maybe...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you took.

Comment: You are welcome!